# What does the command -g means?

Tags: shell, npm

New in programming. When installing a package from npm I am asked to write in the shell:

npm install -g "name_of_package"

What does the -g means? How can I find the name options and meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-g` stands for a "global" install, and you can find the information on the NPM documentation in the command line man page or on their website here:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install.html